# I can't patch a salesforce object using angular and REST api

Tags: javascript, rest-api, angularjs, patch

I'm trying to patch a salesforce object using angular, but am getting no where. Every time I get a nondescript error.

```
salesforce.patch = function(resource, contentType, data) {
  var http = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$http');
  var defered = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$q').defer();
  var log = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$log');

  var upload = function() {
    log.info('Salesforce - Posting resource \'' + resource + '\'.');

    var url = salesforce.proxy.url + resource;
    http({
      method: 'PATCH',
      url: url,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': salesforce.user.accessTokenType + ' ' + salesforce.user.accessToken,
        'Content-Type': contentType,
        'Target-URL': salesforce.user.url
      },
      data: data
    }).success(function(data) {
      defered.resolve(data);
    }).error(function(error) {
      log.error('Salesforce - Failed to post resource \'' + resource + '\'.');
      salesforce.logApiError(log, error);
      defered.reject();
    });
  };

  salesforce.authenticate().then(upload).catch(defered.reject);

  return defered.promise;
};
```

Comment: Try using 'GET' as the httpmethod and append `?_HttpMethod=PATCH` to the URL. I know in apex you have to do it this way

Comment: This didn't work. Isn't GET a retrieval method?

Comment: Yes, but in apex there is not 'Patch" method so you have to hack it. Was just a stab at it

Comment: What exactly is the nondescript error text that you are getting?

Comment: It's nondescript, as in there's no error description. The client I'm working for has a low end version of Salesforce that does not include API errors as a feature from what I'm told.

Comment: The GET method did fix the error, but it didn't actually change anything in Salesforce.

Comment: Are you doing his from within sales-force i.e. in a VF page?

Comment: Nope. This is for an iOS app that's using AngularJS and Ionic

Comment: Can you expand on your post a little bit?  You're not showing us the data you're posting nor the URL you're posting to.  You can mask sensitive data, but it has to be something with your request or the data being submitted perhaps?